# How do I respond when a user mass-upvotes my questions and answers?

Tags: support

A user [thanked me for some minimal help on my part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279964/if-statement-with-multiple-variables-fails-but-each-variables-on-its-own-returns?noredirect=1#comment46760210_29279964) and then said they would "be sure to upvote me."

I promptly received my maximum daily limit of upvotes on past questions and answers within half an hour:

[image: lots of upvotes, all separate to each of my questions and answers]

I think it likely came from that one user.

While I appreciate the kind gesture, I know this isn't right. I don't like garnering reputation the wrong way, and I don't know if the fraud scripts will detect or reverse this. While I'm sure it's likely it will, how do I flag this behaviour myself for a moderator's attention?

Comment: `I don't know if the fraud scripts will detect or reverse this` - oh, it'll get detected and reversed alright.  `how do I flag this behaviour myself for a moderator's attention?`  You don't.  Just thank the user, but ask them to not do that again.  If they *persist* at doing this, daily, then you may need to get a moderator involved.  I'm sure this is a dupe of something, hold on...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Nice on the dupe. I couldn't find that - my Google-fu didn't get me there. Thanks